# where do I get Serial Port Interface API for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serial-port

Can any one tell me where do I get Serial Port Interface API for rails programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ruby-serialport](http://rubyforge.org/projects/ruby-serialport/)?